# List worksheets and associated worksheet IDs from Google Spreadsheet API in Python

Tags: gdata, python-2.x

Have a spreadsheet where the ordering of the worksheets may arbitrarily change, but not the titles.  I would like to list out the titles of all worksheets in a spreadsheet and find the associated worksheet_id.

```
# Google Docs Login information
gd_client = gdata.spreadsheet.service.SpreadsheetsService()
gd_client.email = 'username'
gd_client.password = 'password'
gd_client.source = 'SO demo'
gd_client.ProgrammaticLogin()
# Obtain list feed of specific worksheet. 
feed = gd_client.GetListFeed(spreadsheet_id, worksheet_id)
```

How do I obtain the correct worksheet_id if I do not know what order the worksheets are in, but I do know the title of the worksheet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cleaner way:

```
import urlparse
import os

def worksheet_ids(feed):
  def _id(entry):
    split = urlparse.urlsplit(entry.id.text)
    return os.path.basename(split.path)
  return dict([
    (entry.title.text, _id(entry))
    for entry in feed.entry
    ])
```

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer to my own question modified from [this website](http://www.coderaptors.com/?Script_google_spreadsheets).

```
def PrintFeed(feed):
  for i, entry in enumerate(feed.entry):
    print '%s %s' % (entry.id.text.split('/')[-1], entry.title.text)

def worksheet_dict(feed):
  d = defaultdict(str)
  for i, entry in enumerate(feed.entry):
    d[entry.title.text] = entry.id.text.split('/')[-1] 
  return d

s = gd_client.GetWorksheetsFeed(key=spreadsheet_id)
PrintFeed(s)
wkst_dict = worksheet_dict(feed)
print wkst_dict
```